# MongoDB and Meteor.js - One-To-Many references

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm a complete newbie to Meteor and MongoDB and databases in general so sorry in advance.

I'm building a small, basic web-app that functions like a blog. You have a post, with some things attached to it like title, date etc. I've got that all working except I would like to add tags. I've heard that storing all the tags in each post object would be a bad idea, and instead should be using relationships.

So here's what I've got so far.

```
galleryItems = new Mongo.Collection("galleryItems");
galleryTags = new Mongo.Collection("galleryTags");
```

Two collections in Mongo. One for the items, and one for the tags.

And I have a form that inserts to these two databases.

```
  galleryItems.insert({
    text: text,
    url: url,
    thumbnail: thumbnail,
    createdAt: new Date()
  });

  galleryTags.insert({
    tags: tags, // tags is just an array I have created before this
  });
```

I'm really stuck at how about how to link the two collections together.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB I sometimes purposefully avoid normalizing my data. That's because references are not as easy to work with in document-based databases. Meteor does not make it any easier. It's common to do this in MongoDB - [embedded documents are by nature denormalized](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/#embedded-data-models), for example. There's good information on [data models on the official MongoDB homepage](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

I assume your tags only have a name and no other data? In this case, do you expect to be changing the names of the tags or deleting them? Because those are the only scenarios where storing the tags in each post is going to pose problems. If this is the case, you very likely don't need to separate your tags into a different collection.

But, if you **really** do want to normalize your data, this is how you'd do it. Your `galleryItems` collection would have a field called `tags`, which would store the `_id`s of the tags. E.g.:

```
galleryItems: {
    text: text,
    url: url,
    thumbnail: thumbnail,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    tags: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

And then you'd have a `galleryTags` collection, where you store information about the tags:

```
galleryTags: {
    _id: 1
    name: tagName
}
```

Now you have references to the tags in `galleryItems`, but `galleryItems` doesn't store any information about the tags themselves - to get data about the tags, you'd have to execute a query for that separately.

Comment: Thanks Oskar. I'm going to normalize my data, because I want to show a big list of tags and how many posts are associated to each. THanks so much

Comment: @JordanOverbye If your tags have no data other than a name, then there's simply no point.